# how to load images from excel to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, image, excel, datagridview

I want to load images in the datagridview, but so far I am getting only text.

CODE

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String name = "LOTUS";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\xy\\Downloads\\SCA.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");

            OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
            con.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
```

Comment: is this asp or winforms

Comment: You cannot do this using OlEDB - you will likely need to automate Excel directly and access the images individually.

Comment: any ideas how can I do that? example...

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+automate+Excel&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=

Answer (score 0):

From this [Blog](http://joymonscode.blogspot.co.at/2009/01/reading-image-from-excel-file.html), there is a Solution with the Clipboard.

Something like this way:

```
string shapeName = "";

for (int i = 0; i < sheet.Shapes.Count;i++ )
{
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape shape=sheet.Shapes.Item(i);
   if (shape.Type == MsoShapeType.msoPicture)
   {
      shapeName = shape.Name;
   }
}

Worksheet sheet = GetFirstSheet();
if (sheet != null)
{                    
    Picture pict = sheet.Pictures(shapeName ) as Picture;
    pict.CopyPicture(XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);                 
}

if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
{
   Image img=Clipboard.GetImage();
   pbPicture.Image = img;
}
```